# React - Correct path to display image

Tags: reactjs, image, react-hooks, javascript-objects

I have a React component and want the images to be displayed along with the name/price.

If the images are uploaded to the same folder, can you add these paths as the value for the logo key?

Right now, the images are broken.

There are no console errors or anything.

**COMPONENT**

```
const [products] = React.useState([
    { name: "Mothership", price: 10, logo: "./PHX130.png" },
    { name: "Illideph", price: 20, logo: "./PHX132.png" },
    { name: "Phoenix", price: 30, logo: "./TX15.png" }
  ]);
```

**RETURN**

```
{products.map((product, index) => (
        <Product key={index} product={product}>
          <img src={product.logo} alt="website logo" />
          <button className="button" onClick={() => addToCart(index)}>Add to cart</button>
        </Product>
 ))}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends. If you're using a resources bundler (such as Webpack), you can require it directly and the path will be set for you:

```
<img src={require('./image.png')} />
```

Note that you'll need to have an image loader enabled ([file-loader](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/file-loader/) for webpack).

Otherwise, the path needs to be relative to where your output javascript file is on your server. Eg, if your `main.js` is at `/`, you'll need to have the paths relative to the root of your server.

Comment: Great, your example solved it, appreciate it. will accept when i can

Comment: it's displaying the images but it's saying that each image `has not been transpiled yet`. Would that be an issue?

Comment: I don't understand why it's saying that :/
Here is an example on codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-glade-pkfj3?file=/src/App.js:0-27